# NSDictionary Count

Tags: objective-c, ios

how can I count how many itens do I have inside of "bills"?

```
bills =     (
            {
        id = 1;
        name = "Cursus Nibh Venenatis";
        value = "875.24";
    },
            {
        id = 2;
        name = "Elit Fusce";
        value = "254.02";
    }
);
```

I'm counting this way:

```
NSUInteger keyCount = [resultsDictionary count];
NSLog(@"%i", keyCount);
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what's wrong with the way you are currently doing it?

Comment: exactly , I think you are writing the count to NSLog , is not what you want  ?

Comment: It returns 1 and not 2 as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A naive solution would assume the OP wants to count `bills`, which happens to be an array, so the solution would be

```
NSLog(@"Count: %i", [[resultsDictionary objectForKey: @"bills"] count]);
```

However, if you have a dictionary with more than one object you want to count, then enumerating them all is the only way to go.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSUInteger keyCount = [resultsDictionary count];
NSLog(@"%i", keyCount);
```

is true but also you can use `[resultsDictionary allKeys];` which will return an array of keys and you can directly get its count. For more, please visit [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :v

Answer (score 1):

`NSUInteger count = [bills count];` // top level items in the dictionary

If you want to get ALL items, then you need to use block enumeration and recursively ask every dictionary what the count is and then sum. You have to write code - there is no system provided method to do this. Look at the block enumerations (ie enumerate....) in the class reference.

you can also ask each item what it is - and if "isKindOf:" a NSDictionary or NSArray, get the count, otherwise treat it as 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *billsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
billsArray = [resultsDictionary valueForKey:@"bills"];//returns array
NSUInteger keyCount = [billsArray count];
NSLog(@"%i", keyCount);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Nice! In fact will use this for sure! Thanks!