# Dictionary Size in IOS

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I am developing app like, which will take photos and showing them in thumbnail view as scrolling. I want to restrict the user to take only 50 pictures. If user is trying to take 51th photo I want to show the alert and I want to stop the camera. The taken Pictures are stored in dictionary format. Please help me to do this.

Comment: can you show me your dictionary formate ? so I can help you on same.

Comment: Possiblity of dublicate check this url 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741360/nsdictionary-count

Comment: I want to know that How you are storing the picture in dictionary ? Whole picture or Path to picture ?

Comment: If you put your dictionary in the question, then we can see better.

Answer (score 3):

NSDictionary has a 'count' property with which you can limit the user to take only 50 photos.

For example,

```
if (dict.count > 50) {
//don't show camera and show an alert
} else {
//continue with camera
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get count of keys and values from dictionary like,

```
if([dict objectForKey: @"your key"] count] > 50) {
  //your code
}
```

So you can restrict camera when count is more than 50.